# MVC frameworks for Perl web programming?

Tags: perl, frameworks, cgi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggest some good MVC framework in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470/suggest-some-good-mvc-framework-in-perl)

Are there any frameworks for Perl web programming that uses MVC or something like that? I'm asking this because I'm a C# developer, and I'm used with things like Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC, and, until now, all my research on the subject brought me resources about CGI programmming. Is it still the only way to do web applications in Perl?

Comment: Have a look at this previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470/suggest-some-good-mvc-framework-in-perl

Comment: I don't see this question adding anything that's not already there in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470/suggest-some-good-mvc-framework-in-perl... voting to close

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there are, and perhaps many, but the first that comes to mind is [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/).

Comment: All frameworks cited are great examples, but the answer is for the Catalyst, wich is the most popular and used one.

Comment: Be sure to check the linked question, there are some frameworks that are not listed here, maybe you will find something that suits your needs more than Catalyst.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/).

Comment: Wow! I hear about this one for the first time, and I'm impressed!

Answer (score 8):

[Perl Dancer](http://perldancer.org/) is an interesting looking web application framework in Perl. You can read about comparisons with this and the more established Catalyst in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080017/dancer-vs-catalyst-perl-web-frameworks)

The Dancer "Hello World" looks like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Dancer;

get '/' => sub {
    "Hello World!"
};

dance;
```

..and is executed like this...

```
$ perl bin/app.pl &
...
$ curl http://localhost:3000/
Hello world!
```