# Which module for a FastCGI app in Perl

Tags: perl, fastcgi

Which module would you use if you were to write a FastCGI app in Perl? 
What would be the reasons for your choice?

Comment: Which module would we use for what? Managing FastCGI processes, AS a FastCGI process?

Answer (score 0):

Any modern Perl Web framework could do the job for you. It is going to start a flame war if I choose one, so I am only going to provide you a list about the frameworks that I am aware of.

Check out their syntax and choose one.

It maybe a duplicate of this: [MVC frameworks for Perl web programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283798/mvc-frameworks-for-perl-web-programming)

Dancer: http://blog.leecarmichael.com/2013/01/dancer-nginx-fastcgi.html

mojolicious: http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook

catalyst: http://richard.wallman.org.uk/2010/02/howto-deploy-a-catalyst-application-using-fastcgi-and-nginx/

mason2: http://www.howtoforge.com/running-html-mason-with-nginx-and-fastcgi

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about that at all. I'd write my application to the [PSGI](http://plackperl.org/) specification and then let [Plack::Handler::FCGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack%3a%3aHandler%3a%3aFCGI) handle the deployment.